# PHP - API URL in terminal curl & in browser returns results, but in Gulp / webpack / PHP dev env returns 301?

Tags: php, webpack, gulp

This is driving me insane. I have a PHP project hitting an API and I keep getting a 301 error in my dev environment which is Gulp / Webpack / PHP. The URL returns results fine directly in a browser or a ternimal cURL call.

Any thoughts on where I should look?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // this url works in a browser
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // 301
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to follow the "301 Moved Permanently"

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // this url works in a browser
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and it doesn't work. I'm wondering if there is something with the PHP proxy in the Gulp config that is causing this somehow.